# Django: How to make a list of model instances distinct?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of django model instances, however, some of them might be duplicate, how to get a list which all instances are distinct?

This is not a queryset, but a list, like:

```
instances = [instance1, instance2, ...]
```

What can I do to instances to guarantee all instances are unique?

Comment: when you tell you have a list this list is queryset ? if yes tell me and answer you !

Comment: Take a look my answer ! I have edited it !

Comment: Which database are you using? is `instances` a queryset or a list and how are you getting these `instances` exactly?

Comment: How to get this list is not pertinent, if is a list read my answer i have edited it !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set conversion if you want to use the inherent equality of the objects:

```
instances = list(set(instances))
```

If you want to make them unique based on a property (say `name`), using a dictionary comprehension is one way to do it:

```
instances = { i.name: i for i in instances }.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django ORM's [`.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) method to return distinct model objects.

Comment: The question is asking how to make a list of instances unique, not how to return unique instances from the ORM.

Comment: @user5359531 You could argue that `list(Model.objects.distinct())` would be easier and quicker...

Comment: That is assuming that you are getting your model instances from a single ORM query. But if you actually have a list of instances, not a queryset, then you probably were not getting the model instances from a single queryset. That is why this is not a good answer; obviously if you could get your instances from a single queryset you would have used `Model.objects.distinc()` in the first place.